# Modify an attribute of a thread from other class

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, attributes

I have an problem with my code. I have 2 classes:

- clsSMS
- clsWorker

When my thread is running, I want to modify an attribute of them from my clsSMS class.

```
public class clsSMS
{
    clsWorker objclsWorker;

     public clsSMS(clsWorker objclsWorker = null)
    {
          this.objclsWorker.operatorBlocageError38();
          // The above call doesn't work...
          // I think the objclsWorker  is always null...
          // What do you think?
    }
}


public class clsWorker
{
    public clsSMS clsobjSMS;

    public clsWorker(...)
    {
          this.clsobjSMS = new clsSMS(objclsWorker: this);

    }
    public void operatorBlocageError38(/*String port_concerne, bool erreur38*/)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The method call work fine!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `cls` in front of all your classes?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear from the posted code that you ever instantiated clsWorker.

```
clsWorker worker = new clsWorker();
worker.operatorBlocageError38();
```

If you call operatorBlocageError38 before instantiating, the method has to be marked static.

```
public static void operatorBlocageError38()
```

Comment: No problem. Mistakes are how we learn. If this answer was helpful, please mark as answer.